# Looping functions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested

My goal is to build a looping function that can take the *data and convert it into the *Goal Output

This is as far as I can make it with the code, my fundamental question is how to I nest my code inside of VBA to run 3 lines of code and then skip to line 6

*Data - sheet1

| Layout |
| --- |
| Machine 1 |
| Work Center 1 |
| Date |
|  |
|  |
| Machine 2 |
| Work Center 2 |
| Date |

*Output - sheet2

| Machine | Work Center | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Machine 1 | Work Center 1 | Date |
| Machine 1 | Work Center 1 | Date |

*Goal Output - sheet 3

| Machine | Work Center | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Machine 1 | Work Center 1 | Date |
| Machine 2 | Work Center 2 | Date |

Code

```
    Sub Fill_Data()
    
        Sheet2.Activate
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
        emptyrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        Dim i As Integer
        
        For i = 1 To 3
          ws.Cells(i, 1).Copy
          ws2.Cells(emptyrow, i).PasteSpecial
        Next i
        emptyrow = emptyrow + 1
        
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: If I understood your fundamental question, take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/goto-statement

Comment: Is there always 2 blanks between the next set of values? And is the next set of values always in pairs of 3? The solution will be dependent on the pattern so can you please clarify

Answer (score 1):

The below creates the loop you are asking for, you would just need to modify to your specific need.

```
    Sub Fill_Data()

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    ws.Range("A1").Activate
    emptyrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    
    x = 1
    
    For i = 1 To emptyrow
      ws.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 2, 1)).copy
      ws2.Cells(x, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
      i = i + 4
      x = x + 1
    Next i
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to nest any loops, you just need a couple extra incrementers to track everything.

```
Sub Fill_Data()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim emptyrow As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    With ws2
        emptyrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If emptyrow = 2 Then 'Populate Headers
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Machine"
            .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Work Center"
            .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Date"
        End If
    End With
    
    col = 1
    With ws
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 1 To lr
            If Not .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then 'Skip blanks
                ws2.Cells(emptyrow, col).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                If col = 3 Then 'Reset column and increment row
                    col = 1
                    emptyrow = emptyrow + 1
                Else
                    col = col + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: As I'm working through this code on my actual data, not the test data i provided I am running into the same issue I have before where the copied data doens't seem to index properly and just transposes the same 3 rows of data repeatedly down on my output range. I will look at this more tomorrow and see what my code is doing. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

### Transpose Groups of Data

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeGroupsOfData()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Cells(dlRow + 1, "A")
    
    Dim sfgr As Long ' Source First Group Row
    Dim sr As Long ' Source Row
    Dim dco As Long ' Destination Column Offset
    
    For sfgr = 1 To slRow Step 5
        sr = sfgr
        For dco = 0 To 2
            dCell.Offset(, dco).Value = sws.Cells(sr, "A").Value
            sr = sr + 1 ' next source row
        Next dco
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1) ' next cell below
    Next sfgr
        
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```